# Why Entity Manager flush the same date for each entities?

Tags: php, symfony

I am making fixtures for my entities in symfony 5.2.

One of these represent a magazine with a title, a description and a release date.

My fixture code:

```php
class MagazineFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $intialReleaseDate = new DateTime('1913-04-01');

        for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
            $title = $faker->sentence($nbrwords=6, $variableNbWords=true);
            $number = $i + 1;
            // A magazine is release each month.
            $releaseDate = $intialReleaseDate;
            $intialReleaseDate->modify('first day of next month');

            $magazine = new Magazine();
            $magazine
                ->setTitle($title)
                ->setNumber($number)
                ->setReleaseDate($releaseDate)
            ;
            $manager->persist($magazine);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

The issue is when I run my fixture, each magazine have [the same date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivuxd.png) (which is the last date), I verified all the date by printing them in the for loop and all are correct.

I tried to move the flush method in the for loop and it works! The date are [correctly saved in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1kCN.png).

I learned that the flush method must be called when all entities are persisted and it worked all the time until now. I don't understand why it doesn't work here.

Comment: I believe this is a reference issue. You are using the same instance of `DateTime` in every entity. So, whenever you modify it, it is also modified within the entities. That's why, if you flush at the end, every entity holds the last date.

Comment: And I also believe that using `DateTimeImmutable` would remove this problem and allow you to flush at the end.

Comment: It was that! I replaced ->setRealeaseDate($releaseDate) by ->setRealeaseDate(clone $releaseDate) to passe a copy of the Datetime object and not the reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening has nothing to do with the `flush` method or the Entity Manager in general. The reason this is happening is because variables holding objects don't hold the object itself, but rather an identifier (quote from the [Objects and references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) page):

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

To demonstrate, consider a simple case:

```php
class A
{
    public $b;
}

class B
{
    public $num;
}

$b = new B();
$b->num = 2;
$a = new A();
$a->b = $b;
print_r($a);
$b->num = 4;
print_r($a);
```

The first `print_r` will show the following:

```
A Object (
    [b] => B Object (
        [num] => 2
    )
)
```

The second one will show:

```
A Object (
    [b] => B Object (
        [num] => 4
    )
)
```

Even though we didn't perform any modifications on `$a` itself, by modifying (mutating) `$b`, we've ensured that `$a->b` holds the updated value.

So what's happening in your code is, since `DateTime` is mutable, by modifying it in each iteration you are modifying the same instance that you assign into every entity. That means that, by the end of the loop, every entity will be referencing the modified instance, resulting in the same date being flushed.

Solutions to get around this issue, while still allowing a single `flush` call after the loop, would be either switching to `DateTimeImmutable`, which creates a new instance when modified or passing a clone of the `DateTime` object into your entities.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/icLoE) for the short proof of concept in the question.